# Displaying successful Message on Logout

Tags: php, html

Hello I have been trying to display a message on my login page when I logout from my application and I have been using session_destroy function and make the user be redirected to the Login page using header('location: login.php'); However, when I log out of the system, the successful message could not be found.
Here below is the function that call the logout:

```
if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['id']);
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['verify']);
//set flash message
    header('location: Login.php');
    array_push($successes, "You have been successfully log out of the system");
    }
```

On my login page I have put this included this validation file which should include the successful message accordingly this file is called the validation.php:

```
 <!--Succesful Alert Message displayed on Account Page-->
<?php if (count($successes) > 0 ):?>
    <div class="success">
        <?php foreach ($successes as $success): ?>
            <p><?php echo $success; ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

And I have included it on my Login page as follows:

```
<?php include('Command/controllers/Validation.php'); ?>
```

As of now I can log out successfully but the user would not get any notification message that they have successfully log out of the system, could someone tell me what is wrong with my code please. Also, I have defined the class success in my CSS file.

Comment: 2 seperate scripts cannot see the same variable. Unless you use the session :)

Comment: I need to destroy session to log out so how can I use session to display the successful message ?

Comment: Only throw away the "I am logged in" Stuff. That way you can keep anything else you may need

Comment: Isnt there any means to display a successful log out message on session destroy without using session ?

Comment: Well you could do `header("Location: Login.php?msg=$msg");` and make the `login.php` check for that parameter